# UML class diagram generalization or not?

Tags: uml

The professor requests to draw a class diagram with multiplicity and relationship indicated for following scenario:

> A student taking subjects borrow some textbooks as listed in subject
>   syllabus and some reference books which are not listed in subject
>   syllabus.

I know how to draw the association relationship between student and subject.
But I am not sure whether I should generate the Book class and make two sub-classes for textbook and reference book. My justification is I think textbook and reference book use the same attribute and method. Generalization may be not necessary.

After thinking a few minutes, I may create the Book class with common attribute (title, ISBN, etc.) and create another class BookType to indicate the book type.
But I think BookType can be an attribute to Book class.

As I do not have concrete idea, would anyone give some advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the answer depends by the functional requirements, but I would be oriented to not specify the difference beetween syllabus and reference books, because at the end they are still books, without any particular specification or methods.
 So, I would exclude generalisation and also the addition of a type attribute. At most,if you need to distinguish beetween the two kind of books, you can say that a **Student** holds two different list of borrowed books, **syllabusBooks** and **referenceBooks**.

Comment: I don't think that putting the differentiation into 'Student`'s attributes would give any advantage. Either (I think) it should be a generalization or nothing at all.

Comment: It's hard to say which is the best solution, the question don't specify any functional requirement, but I discarded generalisation to leave the widest flexibilty. The last solution I proposed is related to a possible scenario  in which the user needs to perform different actions on the two subsets of books.